# Partial Derivative Calculation using Change of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation, change-of-variable

I want to verify that $u(x,t)$ is a solution to the semi-infinite heat equation, i.e.
$$ u_t=u_{xx} \ \forall \ x>0, \ t>0 $$
where
$$ u(x,t) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_0^t g(t-\tau)\frac{e^{-x^2/4\tau}}{\tau^{3/2}} d\tau $$
To start, I wanted to find the partial derivative with respect to $t$. Since our bounds are dependent on $t$ we have to use Leibniz integral rule. This yields:
$$ u_t = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}g(0)\frac{e^{-x^2/4t}}{t^{3/2}} + \frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} [g(t-\tau)\frac{e^{-x^2/4\tau}}{\tau^{3/2}}] d\tau $$
Now we are given that $g(0)=0$ so the surface term vanishes. I could pretty easily find that partial derivative since the only thing that's dependent on $t$ is the function $g$. However, I don't think that's going to be fruitful later on when I try to equate this to $u_{xx}$. My thought instead was to use some sort of change of variables to relate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}$ but I'm not quite sure where I would get an equation relating the two. Would it be correct to write:
$$ s = t - \tau \implies t = s + \tau \implies dt = d\tau $$
I feel like there should be a negative sign to the relation but I don't quite see what's wrong with my logic. I also thought to use the chain rule perhaps where:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial t} $$
but then again I need to find what $\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial t}$ is and it's not clear to me how I would do this. Is it just $1$?

Thanks for any advice, help, hints, or links you can provide to clear up my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that $$\frac{\partial g(t-\tau)}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial g(t-\tau)}{\partial \tau}$$

Then, integrate by parts to place the partial derivative with respect to $\tau$ on the kernel function.

Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, I can proceed from that hint - but how are you getting that equation? Can you give a brief justification for it?

Comment: Sure.  Just use the chain rule.